# Reverse string function gives me a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am brushing up on my C/C++ skills. I tried to implement a function that reverses a string but I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) every time I run the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void revstr(char *str);

int main()
{
    char *str = "hello mofo!";
    revstr(str);
    puts(str);

    return 0;
}

void revstr(char *str)
{
    int start = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);
    int mid = len / 2;
    int i, t;
    printf("start: %d, mid: %d,len: %d\n", start, mid, len);

    for ( i = start; i < mid; ++i )
    {
        printf("str[%d] swapping to str[%d]: %c, %c\n", i, len - 1 -i, str[i], str[len - 1 - i]);
        t = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - 1 - i];
        str[len - 1 - i] = t;
    }
}
```

This solution also gives me the same seg fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void revstr(char *str);

int main()
{
    char *str = "hello mofo!";
    revstr(str);
    puts(str);

    return 0;
}

void revstr(char *str)
{
    char *end = str;
    char t;
    if ( str )
    {
        while ( *end != 0 )
            end++;
        end--;

        while ( str < end )
        {
            t = *str;
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't modify literals. Now that I've given useful advice, be aware of `std::reverse` when you go to reverse a string in real code.

Comment: You need to show your work. For example, what line does the segmentation fault occur at?

Comment: Thanks, @chris, I am aware of `std::reverse` but I was trying to do this in C-style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *str = "hello mofo!";
```

`str` is string literal, it's default to `const`, change it is undefined behavior, you want this instead:

```
char str[] = "hello mofo!";
```

Comment: `char *str = "hello mofo!";` **is not the same** as `const char *str = "hello mofo!";`. Also, string literals have the type `char []` and **not** `const char []` for historical reasons.

Comment: @H2CO3: Not according to 2.14.5/8 in the working draft of the standard.

Comment: @H2CO3: Correct `char *str = "hello mofo!";` is not the same as `const char *str = "hello mofo!";`. The second version is correct. The first version relies on a deprecated "feature" of C++. It did not change the type of the underlying type but did change the pointer type so using C libraries was not painful. But resulting in this problem undefined behavior.